# Call to a member function persist() on null when calling a public method from the repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I looked around to see what this problem could be but I don't find anything similar.

Error:

> Call to a member function persist() on null

The exception points me to this line

```
        $this->repository->getEntityManager()->persist($data);
```

In my repository i call the entitity mananger like so

```
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
    parent::getEntityManager();
    }
```

Why does the exception get thrown ?
I'm very confused about this.

Comment: Try `return parent::getEntityManager();`

Comment: Did you mean to just call `parent::getEntityManager();` without returning it?

Comment: @waterloomatt haha yes that was the problem, you can add your comment to the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my repository i call the entitity mananger like so
>
> ```
> public function getEntityManager()
> {
>     parent::getEntityManager();
> }
> ```

Try `return parent::getEntityManager();`

```
 public function getEntityManager()
 {
     return parent::getEntityManager();
 }
```